# monoprogrammed OS

Tags: operating-system

I'm starting studying OS on Tanenbaum's Modern Operating Systems but in my opinion it is too advanced for a beginner,or at least for me, because it starts describing multiprogrammed OS (i.e. modern OS as the title suggests...) when i don't even know what a monoprogrammed OS would look like.
Is there any text covering OS starting with monoprgormmaded and monolitic ones?
(i.e. the simplest kind of OS possible)

Comment: When I read your title I almost started crying immediately because I thought you were trying to program an OS using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). - LOL

Comment: How about MicroC/OS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroC/OS-II ? It's simple and light-weight and there is a book which explains everything: http://www.amazon.com/MicroC-OS-II-Kernel-CD-ROM/dp/1578201039

Comment: There is a Java only os; doesn't seem like to much of a stretch for a C#/Mono OS. [JOS](http://jos.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

this site might help: http://wiki.osdev.org/